# how to do register/login with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm starting my first project with django rest framework.
I've create my own custom user by changing the login with email.
I want first to register an user but I'm already stuck.
I've got the error **'confirm_password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function** when I try to create one.

Here is my serialiser:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields =('id', 'email', 'username', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'confirm_password')
        read_only_fields = ('last_login', 'date_joined')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.save()

            password = validated_data.get('password', None)
            confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

            if password and confirm_password and password == confirm_password:
                instance.set_password(password)
                instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

            return instance
```

Here is my view:

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'les données ne sont pas valides'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And here is my custom user I extends from the **django-custom-user**:

```
class Account(AbstractEmailUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
```

I understand I've got the error because I've not a field confirm password in my model but how do I verify the password without a double input?

I can't find any documentation or tutorial about register/login with the django rest framework so if you know some I'm really interesting in !

Comment: It's not about login, it's about `serializers`. Since `confirmed_password` is not in your model, simply remove it from your `fields = (...)`, and see if it works.

Comment: it works but I can't enter twice a password to verify they're is no error. So I loose this important functionnality @Anzel

Comment: have you got a `form` or some sort? Anyway, you need to validate the `serializers.data['password'] == serializers.data['confirmed_password']` and raise an error or whatever you want manually.

Comment: No I use the form from django rest framework to test. I already validate in my serialisers. It's in my code above

Comment: No you're getting it all wrong. You need to manually validate them. Let me together a sample code for you in a minute

Comment: For the failure, what is the complete callstack that leads up to that failure?

Comment: @RossRogers, I think the errors could be from the `Account` object since there is no `confirmed_password` field in the model, it cannot deserialize it so will raise the `TypeError` invalid keyword.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more reading and seems like `ModelSerializer` doesn't support non-model field for writable, so one way to do it may be using a normal `Serializer` class, like so:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    confirmed_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    # ... and your other fields ...

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password'] != data['confirmed_password']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("passwords not match")
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # ... your create stuff ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # ... and your update stuff ...
```

And you can then use the serializer like a form in your viewset:

```
In [17]: data = {'confirmed_password': '1234',
 'email': 'hello@world.com',
 'password': '1234',
 'username': 'test'}

In [18]: serializer = AccountSerializer(data=data)

In [19]: serializer.is_valid()
Out[19]: True

In [20]: serializer.data
Out[21]: {'email': u'hello@world.com', 'username': u'test', 'password': u'1234'}
```

---

```
In [23]: data = {'confirmed_password': '123456789',
 'email': 'hello@world.com',
 'password': '1234',
 'username': 'test'}

In [24]: serializer = AccountSerializer(data=data)

In [25]: serializer.is_valid()
Out[26]: False

In [27]: serializer.errors
Out[27]: {u'non_field_errors': [u'passwords not match']}
```

Here is the [**doc**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers) where you can read more about the `serializers`, hope this helps.

Comment: I've done what you writte but I still got the error  **The field 'confirm_password' was declared on serializer AccountSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option. **

Comment: I didn't find anything in the doc about registration and login ... I try your code but still got the same issue **The field 'confirm_password' was declared on serializer AccountSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option. **

Comment: @eiffelPower, hey in fact, `ModelSerializer` doesn't like non-model writable fields. I have updated my answer to provide an alternative using normal `Serializer` class. Basically it works like a form, you can do `is_valid()` and raise the `ValidationError` in your view as you like.

Comment: eiffelPower,

Per `"The field 'confirm_password' was declared on serializer AccountSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option. "`  Do you have 'confirm_password' in the `fields` tuple variable on  your `Meta`  class of your serializer?